# Unknown CMake command "ExternalProject_Add"

Tags: cmake, external-project

I have following CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.2 FATAL_ERROR)

project (utils VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

ExternalProject_Add(json-c
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/json-c/json-c.git"
    UPDATE_COMMAND git pull "https://github.com/json-c/json-c.git"

    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL_image/./configure
                      --prefix=${SDL_INSTALL_DIR}

    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/json-c

    INSTALL_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
    )
```

I want to add json-c library to my project, but when I run cmake I'm getting error: Unknown CMake command "ExternalProject_Add". My CMake version is 3.6.2 on OS X

Comment: You missed `include(ExternalProject)`?!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The required module should be part of your cmake installation. But you have to include it into your project with:

```
include(ExternalProject)
```

before the call of `externalproject_add(YOUR STUFF HERE)`. See [Modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html)

There are two include variants:

```
include(<MODULE_NAME_WITHOUT_.cmake>)
include(<FULL_PATH_TO_MODULE_WITH_.cmake>)
```

Examples:

```
include(gcovr)
include(${PROJECT_DIR}/cmake/gcovr.cmake)
```

Modules are plain cmake files and have to be included like your own module files (In case you have them).

The variable `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` is a list of all directories where cmake is loading modules from. You can print out the current value with:

```
message(STATUS "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH=${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")
```

Or you are using smart macros for that. See [CMake](http://www.th-thielemann.de/development/cmake/cmake.html)

Comment: It doesn't work for me : `include could not find load file: ExternalProject.cmake`. But it works with exactly `include(ExternalProject)` as in the answer from @Tsyvarev.

Answer (score 47):

While it is not directly written in documentation pages for versions prior to v3.14, CMake functions described under [cmake-modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html) section requires **including specific module**.

As function `ExternalProject_Add` is described in the [documentation page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) titled as "ExternalProject", you need to use

```
include(ExternalProject)
```

before using it.

---

Same strategy works for any other modules except `Find<name>` ones. Those modules are used via

```
find_package(<name>)
```

Comment: For anyone confused, ExternalProject is not a variable, such as "my_c_project". You have to literally include 'ExternalProject'

Comment: "While it is not directly written in documentation pages" - oh, excellent, I'm just loving CMake more and more. It's so nice when the developers can't be bothered to include required steps in their documentation...

Comment: @Tustin2121 These modules are delivered together with cmake but plain cmake files and have to be included into the CMakeLists.txt like every other external cmake file. 
And starting with v3.14 somebody extended the documentation.