# How can I make CMake download an external package and use it?

Tags: c++, c, cmake

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(CMakeTest)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(event-cmake REQUIRED)

file(GLOB SOURCES "*.cpp" )

add_executable(test ${SOURCES})
```

cmake/Findevent-cmake.cmake:

```
ExternalProject_Add(event-cmake
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libevent/libevent.git
  UPDATE_COMMAND ""
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

I know that the CMakeLists here has no chance to include the resolved package, but I cannot even get CMake to download the external repo. It errors out with:

```
CMake Error at cmake/Findevent-cmake.cmake:3 (ExternalProject_Add):
  Unknown CMake command "ExternalProject_Add".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
```

Is there a way to make it so that cmake will download the project and link to it?

Comment: Did you try to remove the `UPDATE_COMMAND` and `INSTALL_COMMAND` entries?

Comment: Yeah, doesnt help :( same error

Comment: Oh, actually it says that the command itself is not known. Maybe you have a `cmake` tool that's too old, like [version 2.x](http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html) instead of 3.x?

Comment: When tried to move error message into the title, I have found that the question described the same problem already exist: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618522/unknown-cmake-command-externalproject-add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is not directly written in docs, CMake functions described under [cmake-modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-modules.7.html) section **requires including specific module**.

As function `ExternalProject_Add` is described in the [documentation page](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html) titled as "ExternalProject", you need to use

```
include(ExternalProject)
```

before using it.

---

Same strategy is works for any other modules except `Find<name>` ones. Those modules are used via

```
find_package(<name>)
```