# add header files in parent directory

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake, include, include-path

I am trying to include a .h file that is contained inside a directory in its parent. Looks like this:

```
.
├── fan_controller
├── ip_camera
├── motors
├── pose_and_distance
└── serial_communication
```

Edit: They are different "subprojects" each of them containing a independent CMakeList, I am workning in the subproject Fan_controller, with its main and its CmakeList inside it, and I want to use files in the motors directory.

They have different files, I am working in fan_controller's main and I am trying to include a file that is inside motors by doing this:

```
#include "../motors/src/resources/classes/Arduino.h"
```

If I put the global path it works fine:

```
#include "/home/kailegh/catkin_ws/src/project/motors/src/resources/classes/Arduino.h"
```

the thing is that the file is there, I have check it several times and QT autocompletes the path, so it founds it. However when I try to compile, it says:

```
no such file or directory
```

I don't know why this happens, should I add something to the CmakeList? The thing is the file is there!!
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have CMakeLists.txt in the root folder (the folder with fan_controller, ip_camera) add the following **include_directory** statements:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)
...
include_directory(fan_controller/src/resources/classes)
# if required: include_directory(ip_camera/src/resources/classes)
if required: include_directory(motors/src/resources/classes)

set(SOURCES fan_controller/src/resources/classes
    fan_controller/src/resources/classes/myfancontroller.cpp
)

add_executable(myfan_controller)
```

Assuming you have independent projects, you can either use:

- Build and install the subproject and use find_library, see [Usage of sub projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43458181/cmake-solution-sub-directory/43465651#43465651http://)
- Build and install the subproject and use find_package
- ExternalProject, see [Use macro ExternalProject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41618522/unknown-cmake-command-externalproject-add/41629532#41629532)

PS: QtCreator uses the CMakeLists.txt results **and** looks into the filesystem.

Comment: sorry, I ll edit my question, each of them is a different subproject, each of them containing independent CMakeLists there is no root CMakeList

Comment: ummm thanks a lot, I thought I could add them just using the ".."; it seems that only works in header files, when I have tried to use a relative path to a parent un a .cpp it does not work. Thanks a lot, I will try installing them
PS should I accept your answer? maybe someone comes up with something to make it work without installing

Comment: The solution without install is the ExternalProject macro.